# I cannot insert to specific Data Extension Amp script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

I have a cloudpage that is having a form and when I click submit it should have my details saved on the data extension and proceed to the confirmation page

```ampscript
set @prospectsDE = 'Prospects'
      
/* UPDATE Record to SF Object or DE(for Prospects) */
 
 /* For Contact */
 IF @object =="Contact" THEN
  set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care)  

 /* For Lead */
 ELSEIF @object =="Lead" THEN
    /* IF company value is empty */
  IF EMPTY(@company) THEN
      set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email,     
      "Country", @country,
      "State", @state ,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care,
      "T_Cs_Accepted__c", @t_cs_accepted) 
     
   ELSE 
   
    set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname,
      "Email", @email,
      "Company", @company ,
      "Country", @country,
      "State", @state ,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care ,
      "T_Cs_Accepted__c", @t_cs_accepted) 
   


   ENDIF

 /* For Prospects */
  ELSEIF @object =="Prospect" THEN

  SET @updateProspectDE = UpdateDE(@prospectsDE,1,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
     "Last_Name", @lastname, 
     "Email", @email, 
     "Company", @company, 
     "Country", @country, 
     "State", @state,     
     "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
     "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
     "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)     
      
  
 /* For New */
  ElSE
     set @insertProspectDE = InsertDE(@prospectsDE,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
      "Last_Name", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email, 
      "Company", @company, 
      "Country", @country, 
      "State", @state,     
      "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
      "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
      "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)
ENDIF
```

--

The page is perfectly fine when I run it but the problem is I am getting this error upon submitting the form

"This page isn’t workingcloud.info.aroa.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

---

Upon investigating whenever I remove this code

```ampscript
 /* For New */
  ElSE
     set @insertProspectDE = InsertDE(@prospectsDE,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
      "Last_Name", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email, 
      "Company", @company, 
      "Country", @country, 
      "State", @state,     
      "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
      "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
      "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)
```

It run perfectly fine and when I submit I get redirected to thank you page..

Upon digging Ive tried to change the DATA EXTENSION to other data extension so from "PROSPECTS" to prospects clone data extension and I wasnt able to have error when I do this

My question is whats wrong with "PROSPECTS" data extension wherein it is only the same thing of the clone data extension? Why am I having an error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your Data Extension. But if you check the [documentation on InsertDE function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/insertde.html), you will find that it only works in emails:

> This function applies to email messages at send time only.

Instead, you should use [InsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/insertdata.html), which has exactly the same syntax:

```
InsertData('SomeDE','FirstName',FirstName,'LastName',LastName,'CreatedDate',NOW())
```

> Use this function with landing pages, SMS and MMS messages in
> MobileConnect, push messages in MobilePush, and messages in
> GroupConnect.

The issue with InsertDE and InsertData is, that it only INSERTS a record. As you are trying to insert the same record twice (submitting same data in two request), it will fail, as a record with this primary key already exists.

You will need to replace your InsertData with [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/upsertdata.html) function. It will insert a new record, or update an existing record, based on the primary key of your data extension.

Comment: I have tried using this but it's not working too.. I have tried to change the DE and it works I am not sure whats the problem with the old one

Comment: @Rain - I have updated the solution