# I have a cloudpage and using InsertDE function, however it seems that it only working at one submission

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage, form

I have a cloudpage and using InsertDE function, however it seems that it only working at first submission

For example: Scenario 1:

I fill up the form using a new data extension without data and then once I fill up it should insert my records.

However on my 2nd attempt of submission Im having an error like this

This page isn’t workingcloud.info.aroa.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

---

I have tried to clone the data extension and use it again and it works at first submission and continue to have the error at my 2nd submission.. this is the whole code..

```
----
<!-- %%[ 
VAR @subsid, @firstname, @lastname, @email,@company, @country, @state, @i_am_a, @health_care, @t_cs_accepted, @formname, @dummy_subid, @type, @exist, @formsubmit,@accountid 

/* Set initial value */
set @subsid = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey") 
set @firstname = ProperCase(RequestParameter("First_Name"))
set @lastname = ProperCase(RequestParameter("Last_Name")) 
set @email = RequestParameter("Email") 
set @company = RequestParameter("Company") 
set @country = RequestParameter("Country") 
set @state = RequestParameter("State") 
set @i_am_a = RequestParameter("I_Am_A") 
IF @i_am_a == "Clinician" THEN
set @health_care = replace(RequestParameter("Healthcare_Setting"),",",";") 
ELSE
set @health_care = ""
ENDIF
set @t_cs_accepted = RequestParameter("T_Cs_Accepted") 
set @formname = RequestParameter("Form_Name") 
set @dummy_subid = RequestParameter("Dummy_SubsID") 
set @object = RequestParameter("Type") 
set @exist = RequestParameter("exist") 
set @form_type = RequestParameter("Form_Type") 
set @accountid = RequestParameter("AccountId")
set @original_email = RequestParameter("Old_Email")
set @prospectsDE = 'Prospects_Copy1'
set @landingpageDE = 'Landing Page Form Submissions' 

/* If visitor with subscriber key */


set @review = 'true'
  
endif   

/* ########  START Create a case &  Update Landing Page Form Submissions DE  ########  */     
 /* Set case values */  
   set @updateemail = ""
  IF @object == "Contact" AND @original_email != @email THEN
   set @updateemail = Concat("NOTE: Customer has provided a new email address, please update the contact email address from ",   @original_email, " to ",  @email)
  EndIf
  
    Set @character = char(10,2)
    Set @ownerId = "00G3s000002CwBc"
    Set @subject = concat(@formname, " - ", @firstname, " ", @lastname)
  
  IF @object == "Contact" THEN
   Set @description = concat (
        @updateemail, @character,   
      "SubscriberKey: ", @subsid, @character,   
      "Type of record: ", @object,@character,
      "Landing Page Name: ", @formname,@character,
      "First Name: ", @firstname,@character,
      "Last Name: ",  @lastname,@character,     
      "I am a: ", @i_am_a, @character,
      "Health Care Setting: ", @health_care, @character,
      "T&C accepted: ",  @t_cs_accepted)
   
   ELSE    
           Set @description = concat (        
        "SubscriberKey: ", @subsid, @character,   
        "Type of record: ", @object,@character,
        "Landing Page Name: ", @formname,@character,
        "First Name: ", @firstname,@character,
        "Last Name: ",  @lastname,@character,
        "Email: ", @email,@character,
        "Company: ", @company,@character,
        "Country: ", @country,@character,
        "State: ",  @state, @character,
        "I am a: ", @i_am_a, @character,
        "Health Care Setting: ", @health_care, @character,
        "T&C accepted: ",  @t_cs_accepted)
    
    ENDIF
    
    Set @suppliedemail = @email
    Set @suppliedname = concat(@firstname, " ", @lastname) 

     VAR @createCase   
        /* if it's a contact record */
        if @object == 'Contact' then
        SET @createCase = CreateSalesforceObject(
                    "Case",10,           
                    "Subject", @subject,
                    "Description", @description,
                    "SuppliedEmail", @suppliedemail,
                    "SuppliedName", @suppliedname,
                    "ContactId", @subsid,
                    "AccountId", @accountid,
                    "Action__c", "General Enquiry",
                    "OwnerId", @ownerId,
                    "Status", "New",
                    "Origin", "Web"
                    ) 

        else
        SET @createCase = CreateSalesforceObject(
                    "Case",8,           
                    "Subject", @subject,
                    "Description", @description,
                    "SuppliedEmail", @suppliedemail,
                    "SuppliedName", @suppliedname,
                    "Action__c", "General Enquiry",
                    "OwnerId", @ownerId,
                    "Status", "New",
                    "Origin", "Web"
                    ) 
       endif
     
     
     /* If the case is create then update the DE with case number*/
      IF not empty(@createCase) then
        /* Insert a record to DE */ 
          set @rowsUpdated = InsertDE(@landingpageDE, "First_Name", @firstname, "Last_Name", @lastname, "Email", @email, "Company", @company, "Country", @country, "State", @state, "LandingPage_Name", @formname, "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care, "Type", @object, "I_Am_A", @i_am_a, "SubscriberKey", @subsid, "Reviewed", @review, "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted, "Old_Email", @original_email, "CaseID", @createCase )

        ELSE 
          set @rowsUpdated = InsertDE(@landingpageDE, "First_Name", @firstname, "Last_Name", @lastname, "Email", @email, "Company", @company, "Country", @country, "State", @state, "LandingPage_Name", @formname, "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care, "Type", @object, "I_Am_A", @i_am_a, "SubscriberKey", @subsid, "Reviewed", @review, "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted, "Old_Email", @original_email, "CaseID", @createCase )
 
     ENDIF
     
 /* ######## END Create a case &  Update Landing Page Form Submissions DE  ########  */        
     


      
/* UPDATE Record to SF Object or DE(for Prospects) */
 
 /* For Contact */
 IF @object =="Contact" THEN
  set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care)  

 /* For Lead */
 ELSEIF @object =="Lead" THEN
    /* IF company value is empty */
  IF EMPTY(@company) THEN
      set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email,     
      "Country", @country,
      "State", @state ,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care,
      "T_Cs_Accepted__c", @t_cs_accepted) 
     
   ELSE 
   
    set @updateobject = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@object,@subsid,
      "FirstName", @firstname,
      "LastName", @lastname,
      "Email", @email,
      "Company", @company ,
      "Country", @country,
      "State", @state ,
      "I_Am_A__c", @i_am_a,
      "Healthcare_Setting__c", @health_care ,
      "T_Cs_Accepted__c", @t_cs_accepted) 
   


   ENDIF

 /* For Prospects */
  ELSEIF @object =="Prospect" THEN

  SET @updateProspectDE = UpdateDE(@prospectsDE,1,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
     "Last_Name", @lastname, 
     "Email", @email, 
     "Company", @company, 
     "Country", @country, 
     "State", @state,     
     "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
     "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
     "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)     
      
  
 /* For New */
  ElSE
     set @insertProspectDE = InsertDE (@prospectsDE,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
      "Last_Name", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email, 
      "Company", @company, 
      "Country", @country, 
      "State", @state,     
      "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
      "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
      "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)
ENDIF



/* If previous email and new email is not matching - except new */
   IF @original_email != "" AND @original_email != @email THEN
   
 
       
     IF @object == "Prospect" OR @object == "Lead" THEN
      var @subscriberField, @subscriberEncodedsKey, @abort, @sk      
      set @sk = @subsid     
      set @subscriberField = Lookup("ent._Subscribers", "SubscriberKey", "SubscriberKey",@sk)
          IF @subscriberField == @sk then
              var @sub, @updateStatusCode, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode
                set @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
                SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
                SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @sk)   
                set @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
                set @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
                SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
                SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions,"PropertyName","*")
                AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions,"SaveOptions", @saveOptions)
              SET @updateSub = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @updateStatusMessage, @updateErrorCode, @updateOptions) 
      
       ENDIF
      ENDIF
   ENDIF

]%%-->

----

This is the code that is having error

/* For New */
  ElSE
     set @insertProspectDE = InsertDE (@prospectsDE,
      'SubscriberKey', @subsid, 
      "First_Name", @firstname, 
      "Last_Name", @lastname, 
      "Email", @email, 
      "Company", @company, 
      "Country", @country, 
      "State", @state,     
      "Healthcare_Setting", @health_care,     
      "Subscriber_Type", @i_am_a, 
      "T_Cs_Accepted", @t_cs_accepted)


---
```

Please help me :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot insert to specific Data Extension Amp script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/411147/i-cannot-insert-to-specific-data-extension-amp-script). I have added a note on what might be your actual issue.